# Extract strings from url

Tags: php, html

I can't extract these texts from a url, can you help me please?
This is the information that I want to extract and I cannot

```
<p><strong>Días NO lectivos:</strong></p>
    <ul>
    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">9 de octubre:</span> Día de la Comunidad Valenciana</li>
    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">1 de noviembre:</span> Día de Todos los Santos</li>
    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">6 de diciembre:</span> Día de la Constitución</li>
    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">16,17 y 18 de marzo:</span> Aprobación del Consejo Escolar de Godella</li>
    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">19 de marzo:</span> San José</li>
    <li><span style="text-decoration: underline;">1 de mayo:</span> Día del Trabajo</li>
    </ul>
```

this is my code:

```
<?php 

include "simple_html_dom.php";

    $ch = curl_init();

    $url="https://www.epla.es/index.php/2015-06-08-06-16-37/calendario-escolarmy_url";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: You mean scrape using CURL?

Comment: yes i using curl

Comment: post one edited whit my code